# How do do you I insert a sidebar navigation for bootstrap photo gallery?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically have a bootstrap photo gallery for a client who is a graphic designer. I made the gallery but he wants a left sidebar navigation to filter out and display and hide his various work like advertisement, prints, banner ads etc. I've been playing with jquery to do this but I am just trying to get it directly to the left of the photo gallery and be responsive too.

Comment: Use the last tutorial in the answer from arinh and put the gallery in a grid structure (see the Bootstrap docs), with a col-X-4 or col-X-3 and a col-X-8 or col-X-9 so you have two columns one is narrow and one is not. Depending on your class names when you follow the grid structure, it will stack below the breakpoint so I suggest you put the filter first in your html and the gallery next so that on small viewports the buttons/toggles are on the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague as you did not post your code to allow us to distribute what needs to be done. However with the resources you provided, I can at least direct you to a couple of articles that could be useful for you to achieve this affect. May require some playing around with but I guarantee you should come up with a good result and learn from the process.

http://www.webstuffshare.com/2010/05/filter-image-view-using-jquery/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery--net-2907

This one may be the most useful as it already uses bootstrap and you could change the links to be a navbar instead:

http://untame.net/2013/05/how-to-build-a-sortable-image-gallery-with-bootstrap-jquery/

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll check out these tutorials. Not at home to post my code but I will do that asap.